# How do I add an onclick function to a div in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of javascript is meant to add an onclick event to a div.

The div looks like this:

```
<div id="deck0" class="deck"></div>
```

And my javascript has:

```
var i = 1;
document.getElementById('deck0').SetAttribute("onclick", "begin("+i+")");
```

But I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'SetAttribute'
```

Am I doing it right, or is what I am trying to achieve not possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use *setAttribute* to set listeners, not all browsers allow that. Much better to either set the property directly:

```
document.getElementById('deck0').onclick = begin;
```

or use *addEventListener*:

```
document.getElementById('deck0').addEventListener('click', begin, false);
```

If you need to pass a parameter, then:

```
document.getElementById('deck0').onclick = function() {begin(i);};
```

similarly for *addEventListener*.

Note that earlier versions of IE don't support *addEventListener* so you will need a cross–browser function to feature test for support. Where lacking, test for *attachEvent* and fall back to the direct property method. Search for "addEvent" functions, there are plenty of examples.

Comment: Setting the onclick property is part of DOM 0, so it works in every browser that supports javascript, right back to Navigator 2 and IE 3. Setting the property is great if you only have one listener (which is the vast majority of cases), you need to be a little more clever when adding multiple listeners.

Comment: Okay thanks RobG :) Also if im adding an onclick via html method <div onclick=""> does that work the same way or is that the attribute method with limited support?

Comment: Setting inline listeners (i.e. the attribute in the markup) is fine and supported everywhere, just keep them concise.

Comment: here's an example of the cross-browser way for adding an event listener: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1724445/56829

Answer (score 4):

Javascript is case-sensitive.
That should be `setAttribute`.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is case-sensitive, you'd need to write [it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute) lowercase.

Apart from that, to set [event listeners](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html) no [attributes](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html) should be used. This would need a string to be evaluated each time - you can do better from a script. Instead, assign a function to the [`onclick` property](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html):

```
document.getElementById('deck0').onclick = function(event) {
    begin(1);
};
```

[Advanced event registration](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html) would be even better, but is more complex because Microsoft lacks supporting the standard.

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways to associate a function to the `onclick` event :

```
function deck0_onclick() {
    begin(i);
}

document.getElementById('deck0').onclick = deck0_onclick;
```

Or directly :

```
document.getElementById('deck0').onclick = function() {begin(i);}
```