# Image can't be shown by javascript in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

Below is my html code for image.

```
 <img src="" id="displaymirrorimage" height=auto width=auto style="display: none;">
```

Below is my javascript code for show image dynamically on mouseover.

```
document.getElementById("displaymirrorimage").style="display:block;";
```

It's working fine in Firefox and Chrome but can't work in Internet Explorer and Safari browser.

Comment: Try `document.getElementById('displaymirrorimage').style.display = 'block';`

Comment: Did you check this post ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724342/onmouseover-doesnt-work-when-using-javascript-to-add-img-tag-on-ie

Comment: Make sure your `height=auto` and `width=auto` are not causing the issue. Pull those out and see what happens. In the older days, IE choked on this, but you did not specify a version of IE.

Answer (score -1):

Try:
`document.getElementById("displaymirrorimage").style.display="block";`

Comment: copying @DavidR 's comment and posting it as your own answer...it's not a good practice

Comment: I had answered it earlier.

Comment: Sry for the earlier comment. I did not see the comment when I answered the question, it was not present.

Comment: When I first saw the question there were no comments. I started working on the question, in meantime I did not refresh the page. After I got the answer I posted it & closed the tab.